# iOS UIImageView resize issue

Tags: ios, uiimageview, interface-builder, autolayout

I've came across some strange behaviour of UIImageView. I layout my imageView in IB so it takes up the whole view controller's view. Resizing is set to Scale to Fill. But I still see some border around the image. I changed imageView's background color to light blue so it's a little bit easier to see the problem. Not sure what's causing this behaviour. Why the image is not taking up all the space?

[image]

Comment: Just to make sure: your image does not have a transparent border, does it?

Comment: You are right, it does have a transparent border! Just to be clear - it's not me who made the image. Damn those designer guys! Thanks a lot for the tip.

Comment: Ah, designers-shmisigners... [If you want something done, do it yourself :-)](https://youtu.be/lbDoZTs3NoY?t=1m8s)

Comment: I completely agree with you. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image had a transparent border in itself. Problem solved. Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Check if "Constrain to margins" is disabled.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, it was the first thing I checked. Thanks for the tip. Turned out border was inside the image itself.